# index to use for pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

New to SQL.  I have an unindexed table of about 20 million records, that has one row per task, I need one row per job, with each job row containing the task and task dates.  I use a pivot to accomplish this which is working.  I am having some huge tempdb growth which is problemeatic.  I need help tuning this query.  When I look at the Execution plan I see about 80% is due to a table scan.  I figure indexing the source table would help, but I'm not sure how to index.

```
SELECT Job
    ,TSK_CD + 'F' AS TaskCode
    ,CAST(FORECAST_DATE AS SMALLDATETIME) AS TaskDate
FROM Task_Details AS FcstDateQuery
WHERE FORECAST_DATE IS NOT NULL

UNION

SELECT Job
    ,TSK_CD + 'A' AS TaskCode
    ,CAST(ACTUAL_DATE AS SMALLDATETIME) AS TaskDate
FROM Task_Details AS ActDateQuery
WHERE ACTUAL_DATE IS NOT NULL
) AS TaskDateQuery

PIVOT(MAX(TaskDate) FOR TaskCode IN (
            [Code1F]
            ,[Code1A]
            ,[Code2F]
            ,[Code2A]
            ,[Code3F]
            ,[Code3A]
                    <... a bunch of other task codes>

            )) AS Piv
```

Source table has columns

```
 Job 
,TSK_CD
,FORECAST_DATE
,ACTUAL_DATE
```

Resulting table has:

```
Job   Code1F   Code1A   Code2F  Code2A  Code3F   Code3A....
```

Id be grateful on pointers on how to index the source table or improve the query.  The source table is static data (changes once a day via a push to me).  I use the query to build a target table.

Comment: Are those all the columns the source table has?

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: Index all columns in `where`, all `output columns` and all `columns used (order by, group by, pivot...)`.

But your problem can be differend - in your case `UNION` and `concatenated fields` - it force your pivot to not use indexes. You can see it in execution plan.

Comment: Source table columns after where it says "Source table has columns"

Comment: SQL Server 2014

Comment: index all columns in where,....  Noob, so not sure what you mean.  New to indexing of any kind :(  Appreciate the help though.

Comment: You could also consider a columnstore index then.

Comment: Will you elaborate on the columstore index?  Why it's a fit, how to do it, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Covering index:

```
create nonclustered index ix_Task_Details__Job_Tsk_Cd_cover)
  on dbo.Task_Details (Job,Tsk_Cd)
    include (Forecast_Date,ActualDate)
```

You might try conditional aggregation instead of `pivot()`:

```
select 
    Job
  , [Code1F] = max(case when Tsk_Cd='Code1' then ForeCast_Date end)
  , [Code1A] = max(case when Tsk_Cd='Code1' then Actual_Date end)
  , [Code2F] = max(case when Tsk_Cd='Code2' then ForeCast_Date end)
  , [Code2A] = max(case when Tsk_Cd='Code2' then Actual_Date end)
  , [Code3F] = max(case when Tsk_Cd='Code3' then ForeCast_Date end)
  , [Code3A] = max(case when Tsk_Cd='Code3' then Actual_Date end)
from dbo.Task_Details
group by Job
```

Comment: Aggregation was faster.  Thank you.